# Oracle SQL syntax left join

Tags: sql, oracle

I've encountered some Oracle sql syntax I haven't seen before (see below). I'm not exactly sure how TABLE2 is being joined to TABLE3.

```
SELECT A.FIELD, B.FIELD2, C.FIELD3
FROM 
TABLE1 A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(TABLE2 B 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 C ON B.ID = C.ID and B.NAME = C.NAME ) 
ON 
A.ID = B.ID and A.NAME = B.NAME and A.BDATE = B.BDATE
```

Is the query above the same as:

```
SELECT A.FIELD, B.FIELD2, C.FIELD3
FROM 
TABLE1 A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.ID and A.NAME = B.NAME and A.BDATE = B.BDATE
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C ON B.ID = C.ID and B.NAME = C.NAME
```

Comment: It could be instructive to prefix your query with `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR` and then compare the query plan for both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses control the logical order of evaluation.  For an inner join, parentheses do not matter.  It requires more thought for a `left join`.

I'm pretty sure that for a sequence of only `left join`s, the parentheses do not matter.  The issue is when records are in some tables but not all of them.  In both cases, the set of final records is based on "A".  And any table in "B" and matches "A" should have its columns from "B".  Similarly, "C" is in the results only if it matches both "A" and "B".